# Using the $inc function across the MongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I am currently working on a moderation system for my Discord bot and came across an unexpected issue. I've been using the $inc function to increase the values for a single document, though I have sadly not achieved to use the $inc function across multiple different documents, meaning I would like to increase ($inc) the value of the new document according to the numbers of the previous document.

Example: [Cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCX3s.png)

Current code:

```
async run(client, message, args, Discord) {

    const targetMention = message.mentions.users.first()
    const userid = args[0]
    const targetId = client.users.cache.find(user => user.id === userid)
    const username = targetMention.tag

    if(targetMention){
       
        args.shift()

        const userId = targetMention.id
        const WarnedBy = message.author.tag
        const reason = args.join(' ')

        if(!reason) {
            message.delete()
            message.reply('You must state the reason behind the warning you are attempting to apply.').then(message => {
                message.delete({ timeout: 6000})
            });
            return;
        }

        const warningApplied = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffd200')
        .setDescription(`A warning has been applied to ${targetMention.tag} :shield:`)

        let reply = await message.reply(warningApplied)
        let replyID = reply.id

        message.reply(replyID)

        const warning = {
            UserId: userId,
            WarnedBy: WarnedBy,
            Timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
            Reason: reason,

        }

        await database().then(async database => {
            try{
                await warnsSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    Username: username,
                    MessageID: replyID
                }, {
                    $inc: {
                        Case: 1
                    },
                    WarnedBy: WarnedBy,
                    $push: {
                        warning: warning
                    }
                }, {
                    upsert: true
                })
            } finally {
                database.connection.close()
            }
        })
    }
    if(targetId){
       
        args.shift()

        const userId = message.member.id
        const WarnedBy = message.author.tag
        const reason = args.join(' ')

        if(!reason) {
            message.delete()
            message.reply('You must state the reason behind the warning you are attempting to apply.').then(message => {
                message.delete({ timeout: 6000})
            });
            return;
        }

        const warning = {
            userId: userId,
            WarnedBy: WarnedBy,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
            reason: reason
        }

        await database().then(async database => {
            try{
                await warnsSchema.findOneAndUpdate({
                    userId,
                }, {
                    $inc: {
                        Case: 1
                    },
                    WarnedBy: WarnedBy,
                    $push: {
                        warning: warning
                    }
                }, {
                    upsert: true
                })
            } finally {
                database.connection.close()
            }
            const warningApplied = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ffd200')
            .setDescription(`A warning has been applied to ${targetId.tag} :shield:`)
            message.reply(warningApplied)
            message.delete();
        })
    }
}
```

Schema attached to the Code:

```
const warnsSchema = database.Schema({
    Username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    MessageID: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Case: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    warning: {
        type: [Object],
        required: true
    }
})
module.exports = database.model('punishments', warnsSchema)
```

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67781826/edit) and show us your current code.

Comment: Sure thing! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question. For all of those who are attempting to do exactly the same as me, there is an easier way to get this to properly work. The $inc (increase) function will not work as the main property of a document. An easier way to implement this into your database would be by creating a .json file within your Discord bot files and adding a line such as the following:

```
{
 "Number": 0
}
```

After that, you'd want to "npm i fs" in order to read directories in live time.
You can proceed to add a function to either increase or decrease the value of the "Number".
You must make sure to import the variable to your current coding document by typing:

```
const {Number} = require('./config.json')
```

*config.json can be named in any way, it just serves as an example.*

Now you'd be able to `console.log(Number)` in order to make sure the number is what you expected it to be, as well as you can now increase it by typing `Number+=[amount]`

Hope it was helpful.